# Android dialog cause Memory Leak

Tags: android, memory-leaks

```
@Suppress("FINITE_BOUNDS_VIOLATION_IN_JAVA")
abstract class BaseQMUIDialogBuilder<T : QMUIDialogBuilder<T>, D : ViewDataBinding>(context: Context) : QMUIDialogBuilder<T>(context) {

    protected var mBinding: D? = null

    override fun onCreateContent(dialog: QMUIDialog, parent: QMUIDialogView, context: Context): View? {
        mBinding = DataBindingUtil.bind(LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(getContainerId(), null))
        onCreateContentAfter(dialog, parent, context, mBinding)
        dialog.setOnDismissListener { onQMUIDialogStateChanged(0) }
        dialog.setOnShowListener { onQMUIDialogStateChanged(2) }
        dialog.setOnCancelListener { onQMUIDialogStateChanged(1) }
        return mBinding?.root
    }

    open fun onQMUIDialogStateChanged(state: Int) {
        L.e("onQMUIDialogStateChanged state=$state")
    }

    open fun onCreateContentAfter(dialog: QMUIDialog, parent: QMUIDialogView, context: Context, mBinding: D?) {
    }

    abstract fun getContainerId(): Int

    override fun show(): QMUIDialog {
        return super.show()
    }

}
```

[User android studio profiler](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jlCfz.png) was detected that there was a memory leak in onCreateContent, but I don't know which line caused it.

Comment: You can do two things to avoid leak . `dismiss` the dialog in `Activity#onDestroy` if its still active of you are holding a reference to it . Second unbind and nullify the binding in Dialog when its get dismiss.

Comment: Calling mBinding?.unbind () in the setOnDismissListener method will still leak the memory. What else do I have to do?

Comment: You need to assign null to it . You can use [leak-canary](https://square.github.io/leakcanary/) to see what exactly is causing leak . and provide leak stacktrace with question .